# Bind images to GridView from database without using handler or httphandler

Tags: c#, asp.net

have read many article and most of the article suggest httphandler or handler for image binding to gridview from SQL Server.

Is it  possible to bind images from database to gridview  without httphandler or handler?.
If yes than provide me sample code

**My table schema:   Table Name:- ImageGallery**

```
Column Name     DataTypes

Photo           image


 The above table stored the images in <Binary data>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes. Is it a good idea? Not at all, and here's why. An `HttpHandler` is a way of providing a virtual URL for the image. This allows the browser to handle the `GET` requests on its own, in an order that's efficient, and asynchronously. This further means that the initial `GET` request isn't burdened down with conceivably MB's of images.

The idea of a website is that it's more efficient to make a lot of smaller requests asynchronously than it is to make one massive request. Why? Because you're already at a disadvantage to provide the user with a good experience when disconnected from the server. Adding insult to that injury by making a massive request that could take minutes, isn't going to add to their joy.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Instead of storing image as Binary datatype in database, U can try an alternate Solution.


 1. Make the column datatype as varchar or nvarchar.

 2. Store your image in a seperate folder.

 3. Fetch the url for that Image.

 4. Save it in the Database.

 5. Now in your gridview mention tha column data according to ur wish.

 6. During Runtime the URL will refer to the content and the image will
    be displayed in your Gridview.
```